# Unable to install Ubuntu on Lenovo T470, kernel error for i686

Tags: system-installation, 64-bit, qemu, canonical

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo T470. It currently has Windows 10. In **System Properties** it shows Windows 10, 64-bit OS, x64 processor.

When I try to install Ubuntu from pen drive nothing happens, so tried xboot QEMU to emulate. In QEMU it showed the error

> This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.

I searched for this issue on Ask Ubuntu, and I found that the solutions provided were for setting up Ubuntu in virtual machines by enabling virtualization from BIOS, so I enabled virtualization from BIOS and tried again... but got the same error.

Some other answers suggest downloading and burning a 64-bit image, which I already have, but it didn't work.

I tried with an old Lubuntu-i386 image and surprisingly it worked.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: No definitely it is not. Kindly have a look at issue and description pls

Comment: It is new laptop, so I think that you should download any modern Ubuntu LTS installer and then boot it in default UEFI mode. Also you may consider to check your BIOS settings for misconfiguration.

Comment: Downloaded ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and disabled secure boot option, enabled leagcy & uefi (both mode) from bios

Comment: what do you mean "nothing happens" when you try to install? Could you please elaborate on what kind of nothing is happening? Are you trying to install alongside Windows? Please make sure you install in UEFI mode if so. How are you making your installation media? See [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](//askubuntu.com/q/674441) for help.

Comment: The system tries to boot into/from pen drive but after a couple of seconds, it brings back to boot options..

Comment: If this is a new laptop, try using 18.10. It has support for newer hardware.

Comment: Yes, it is a new laptop.. ill give 18.10 a try.. but as mentioned the older isos i386's are working fine. So i'm confused

Comment: Please keep me posted at @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema nope ubuntu 18.10 also didnt work. But surprise backtrack 64bit worked... I dont understand what is going on

Comment: What is backtrack, another linux variant?

Comment: @heynnema yes its another linux variant aimed at hackers and security related ppl

Comment: Installed ubuntu16.04-i386.. it got installed and working. But having to find alternative to some softwares like chrome who have discontinued 32bit support. Anyways if anyone finds any proper solution for i686 architecture, let me know. Windows 64 bit was running properly on this machine